# Best way to keep containers equal size using percentage (CSS/Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pop up, in the pop up there are 2 divs that are side by side. To give an example:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="parentContainer" style="display:inline; width:100%">
    <div id="childContainer" style="display:inline; width:50%">content</div>
    <div id="childContainer" style="display:inline; width:50%">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The divs on a large screen will behave as normal and be side by side in the container.

The problem I have is that on a phone, when resized the childContainers width's become relative to a smaller screen and does not fill the width of the popup like in a bigger screen.

How can I make sure that if the div goes onto a new line in the pop up's parent container it takes up the width of the new line. Thanks

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `<head>` section of your `index.html` file?

Comment: yes I do , it looks like this:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's column classes to move the content to a new line on smaller devices. In the example below, the parent container will always be 100% width, based on the popup's width. The child containers will have 50% width until your device's pixel width is < 768px. Devices below that pixel width will cause the child containers to take up 100% of the width, and appear in rows.

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="parentContainer" class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="childContainerA" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Content A</div>
        <div id="childContainerB" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Content B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked thanks. How do I increase the width of the column?

Comment: The width of these columns is determined by the width of their parent divs. The width percentages can be changed by changing the number at the end of the col class. Examples can be found here: [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)